# There is always that one celery worker process, can't use kill command because the PID is constantly changing

Tags: django, redis, django-celery, worker

I'm in the process of developing a project and I'm working on implementing background tasks and notifications for user feedback. I'm using Django in conjunction with Celery for task management and Redis as a message broker.

Currently, I can successfully execute background tasks, but I've encountered an issue when attempting to gracefully stop the Celery worker and exit Redis.

Here's my terminal output:

```bash
ps aux | grep 'celery worker'                    
aysegul           2577   0.0  0.0 408102576   1072 s001  R+   11:35AM   0:00.00 grep celery worker
```

Then;

```bash
sudo kill -9 2577                                         
Password:
kill: 2577: No such process
```

Then I tried:

```bash
celery -A request_handler.celery control shutdown
```

Last command gave me connection errors caused by multiple sources:

```bash
redis.exceptions.ConnectionError: Error 61 connecting to localhost:6379. Connection refused.
```

I came across this command but it didn't work neither:

```bash
ps auxww | grep 'celery worker' | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9         
kill: 2713: No such process
```

I'm somewhat puzzled by this situation and wonder if this lingering process is necessary. I've even restarted my computer, yet the issue persists since yesterday. Could you kindly provide insight into the purpose of this lingering process and whether it's a matter that requires attention? Thank you.